# Error in java when creating Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Error in java when creating Threads.  The error is in "MainApp" with RandomCharacterThread being the error.  The Thread t1 is expecting a char whereas i am giving it an int value.  This is what had caused the error.  I have added comments to make the code clearer for the community.

```
//Main class.
//program to display random numbers and characters using threads.
public class MainApp 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainApp().start();
    }
    public void start()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread (new RandomCharacterThread("1"));
        t1.start();

    }

}


//RandomCharacterThread.
//Imports.
import java.util.Random;
//=====================================================================
public class RandomCharacterThread implements Runnable
{
//Variables.
    char letter;
    int repeats;
    Random rand = new Random();
//Constructor
//=====================================================================
public void RandomCharacterThread(char x)
{
    letter = x;
    repeats = rand.nextInt(999);
}
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        for(int i = 0;i < repeats; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Character: " + letter);
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Its usually a bad idea to discard exceptions.

Comment: In this case you don't need the try/catch block. Remove it and if a RuntimeException or Error is thrown it will be printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "constructor" takes a `char` as an argument; you're passing a `String`. You'd want to do something like

```
    Thread t1 = new Thread (new RandomCharacterThread('1'));
```

Note the single quotes rather than double quotes, which makes this a `char` constant rather than a `String` with one character.

I say "constructor" in quotes because you actually don't have one: you have a method that returns void with the same name as the class. Remove the "void" and you'll be good. Constructors have no return type at all:

```
public RandomCharacterThread(char x) 
{
    ...
```

This is a very common newbie mistake, but most people only make it once!

Comment: i've still got the error.  The error only disapears when there is nothing in the parameters.  Also nothing is printing out from the Thread.

Comment: @ConorPendlebury:  Ah! I see the other problem: see my edited answer.

Comment: that work thanks.  I was looking through some recent work and i have public class subClass(String x).  Why would you say i couldnt use class in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of class `RandomCharacterThread` is expecting argument of type char , where as you are passing a string, which throws error.

This is the correct version.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread (new RandomCharacterThread('1'));
```